# How Python adds current directory to sys.path

Tags: python, import, path

I have a directory like this, located in `myDir/`.

```
myDir
  └── importExample
         ├── __init__.py
         └── printPath.py
```

and `printPath.py`:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I understand that Python would add "current directory" to the `sys.path`. However, I found running the script directly and running using `-m` have different behavior.

```
~/myDir$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/yy0125/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

~/myDir$ python importExample/printPath.py 
['~/myDir/importExample', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/yy0125/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

~/myDir$ python -m importExample.printPath
['~/myDir', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/yy0125/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Two questions:

1. What is "current directory"? The place where we run the command? Or where the file is located?
2. Why use `-m` cause different behavior (in the first entry of `sys.path`)?

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation ([Search for sys.path paragraph](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)):

```
As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory
containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script
directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python
to search modules in the current directory first.
```

When you're running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` it means
that you're running it in interactive shell mode, so sys.path[0] is none.

In second case you're running *printPath* script, so sys.path[0] is directory where this script is located.

Third case is a bit different. sys.path[0] is your current working directory, because python automatically adds your current working directory to sys.path before searching for *importExample* module

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide a link for the doc you are referring to? Especially for the 3rd case.